# Is $\frac {\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

How would someone show $$x\mapsto\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0, \infty)$? Also that

$$\int_{[0,\infty)} \frac {\sin^2(x)}{x^2} d\lambda = \int_{[0,\infty)} \frac {\sin(x)}{x} d \lambda$$

My thoughts so far:

$$\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$$
Since $1/x^2$ is Lebesgue integrable, then $\sin^2x/x^2$ must be as well.

But I don't know how to proceed with showing the other part.

Comment: I'm not sure what $six$ is supposed to be in the integral equality line. Did you mean $\sin(x)$?

Comment: $1/x^2$ is not Lebesgue measurable in $[0,\infty)$

Comment: I think I have seen these integrals done before by taking the real/imaginary part of an complex integrand

Comment: The six should be sin(x), sorry!

Comment: Also, I've seen the complex integral way of doing it before, but this is studying for a real analysis qualifying exam (no complex analysis theorems allowed)

Comment: The title does not have the differential, but I am not sure if it is $d\lambda$ or $dx$, so if someone knows please edit it and add it, many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1\quad\text{as $x\to 0$},
$$
there is some $\delta > 0$ and some $M > 0$ such that
$$
\bigg|\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\bigg|< M\quad \text{if $0\le x < \delta$}.
$$
Since everything in sight is non-negative, by additivity,
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_0^\delta\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx + \int_\delta^\infty\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx,
$$
and the first integral is convergent because it is bounded above by $M\delta$. The second integrand is bounded above by $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x^2}$, which belongs to $L^1\big([\delta,\infty)\big)$, by the $p$-test if you like. Hence $x\mapsto \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

AOrtiz has shown that the integral is convergent. To complete the answer, I will show that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin^2x}{x^2}\,dx= \int_0^\infty \frac {\sin x}{x}\,dx.
$$
Take $\epsilon>0$. Then, integrating by parts and using that $2\sin^2x=1-\cos(2\,x)$, we have
\begin{align}
\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac {\sin x}{x}\,dx&=-\frac{\cos x}{x}\Bigr|_\epsilon^\infty-\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac {\cos x}{x^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\cos\epsilon}{\epsilon}-\int_{\epsilon/2}^\infty \frac {\cos(2\,t)}{2\,t^2}\,dt\\
&=\frac{\cos\epsilon}{\epsilon}+\int_{\epsilon/2}^\infty \frac {1-\cos(2\,t)}{2\,t^2}\,dt-\int_{\epsilon/2}^\infty \frac {dt}{2\,t^2}\\
&=\frac{\cos\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}+\int_{\epsilon/2}^\infty \frac {\sin^2t}{t^2}\,dt.
\end{align}
Let $\epsilon\to0$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that $\int^1_0\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx$ is Riemann integrable, hence Lebesgue integrable. On the other hand, the Dominated Convergence Theorem shows that $\int^\infty_1\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx$ is Lebegue integrable:

consider the sequence of functions $g_n(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\chi_{[1,n]}(x)$  and note that $g_n(x)\le f(x)=1/x^2$. Since $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, we may apply the DCT to conclude that $\lim g_n(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Now, combining these two integrals, using the additivity of the Lebegue integral, we have that $\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx\in L^1(\mathbb R).$

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem? I don't think you mean that. More like "comparison test" or something.

Comment: Yes, I mean DCT, in the parlance of the Lebesgue Integral. If you mean Improper Riemann integral, then there comparison test is fine, but I resist using the term here because there are convergent Improper Riemann integrals whose integrands are not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: The DCT is a theorem about when it is okay to exchange an integral with a limit, which is not apparently how you are intending to use it here, unless you're obfuscating a sequence of functions converging pointwise to another one that I'm not picking up on.

Comment: I think you are thinking of the DCT applied to counting measure. The theorem  also is true for  Lebesgue measure. There is a good introduction to the Lebesgue measure in Royden's Real Analysis book or just see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

Comment: The statement of DCT is the following: If $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions such that $|f_n| \le g$ for each $n$ with $g\in L^1$ (of whatever our measure space is, counting measure, or what have you), and if $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., then $f$ is integrable and $\int|f-f_n| \to 0$. If you still insist that you are applying the DCT, please point out what sequence of functions you're using, and to what end.

Comment: $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\chi_{[1,n]}(x)$. Sorry, these calculations are standard, so I omitted the steps that I considered obvious.

Answer (score -4):

Show that $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2\!x}{x^2}$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$ and you are done.

Comment: How would that show $\int_{[0,\infty)} \frac{sin^2x}{x^2} = \int_{[0,\infty)} \frac{sinx} {x}$ ?

Comment: Tell me downvoters, why this answer is wrong.

Comment: @timur you seem to be saying that continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ are all integrable, which is clearly false.

Comment: @qbert: That is true but the only nontrivial part of the question was whether it is integrable near 0. One needs to leave some part of the question to the student.

Comment: those seem equivalently clear to me. Also, it isn't continuous on the interval you say as it isn't defined at $0$. It extends to a continuous function at $0$, however

Comment: Well that's how mathematicians talk. A shorthand, if you will.

Comment: @timur that's fair enough, I just thought the answer risked confusing the student. In any event, i will remove my downvote. edit: I cannot as it has not been edited